# graphql mutation gives syntax error: Expected Name

Tags: graphql

I am trying to implement mutations with a variable. But I get the following error:

```
"Syntax Error GraphQL request (3:22) Expected Name, found $

2:     mutation {
3:       createProperty($property) {
                        ^
4:         id
"
```

My schema definitely doesn't say anything about a name, that's why I think this error is so strange.. I also don't think the documentations about graphql / apollo are very good.

**Calling the mutation from client:**

```
const property = {
    title: 'First house',
    cost: 849,
    bedrooms: 3,
    bathrooms: 2,
    car_spaces: 1,
    house_size: 60,
  };

  const createPropertyQuery =
  graphql(gql`
    mutation {
      createProperty($property) {
        id
      }
    }
  `, {
      options: {
        variables: {
          property,
        },
      },
    });


  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: createPropertyQuery,
  });
```

**Schema:**

```
type Property {
    title: String!
    cost: Float
    user: User
    bedrooms: Int!
    bathrooms: Int!
    car_spaces: Int!
    house_size: Int!
}
input propertyInput {
    title: String!
    cost: Float
    bedrooms: Int!
    bathrooms: Int!
    car_spaces: Int!
    house_size: Int!
}

type RootMutation {
    createProperty (
        property: propertyInput
    ): Property
}
```

Comment: You'll need to modify your query and actually declare the variable you are sending inside your operation definition. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131876/6024220) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphQL - Syntax Error GraphQL request (5:15) Expected Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130386/graphql-syntax-error-graphql-request-515-expected-name)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should mention name of the parameter at first!

```
mutation CreatePropertyMutatuin($property: propertyInput){
  createProperty(property: $property) {
    id
  }
}
```